# Why this javascript class returns undefined

Tags: javascript, class, this

I have this simple Javascript code to write some modules, but I don't know why I get undefined results even when I'm calling the function from inside:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function testFunction() {
        this.hours = null;
        function getHours() {
            return this.hours;
        }

        alert(getHours());
        return {
            getHours: function () {
                return getHours();
            }
        }
    }

    var test = new testFunction();
    alert(test.getHours());

}
```

I think I've problem in understanding `THIS` keyword in javascript and using it inside javascript constructors.

Thank you.

Comment: The `this` inside your `getHours` function is not the same `this` outside of it.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin What is the different? I want to understand THIS really! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Mohammad it's very simple - if you call `obj.myFunc()` then `this === obj`.  But if you just call `myFunc()` then `this === window` (or `null` in ES5 strict mode!)

Comment: Nice! That makes sense for me, as @Alnitak says the problem then in my return public object, but his answer didn't work for me.

Comment: @Mohammad yes, because the returned public object doesn't contain the `hour` property!   That could have been added to the returned object too, but then it wouldn't have been private.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you, now i understand it and apply it with prototypes in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (initial) problem is here:

```
return {
    getHours: function () {
        return getHours();
    }
}
```

By making a "naked" call to `getHours()` inside this function you're losing any `this` context that you had.

Instead, do this:

```
return {
    getHours: getHours
}
```

i.e. return an object that contains a reference to the desired function.  When you call `test.getHours()` it'll then correctly pass `test` as `this` to `getHours`.

The other issue is that because you're using `return` to expose a set of functions, that returned object becomes the newly constructed `this` and it *no longer refers to the `this` that you added `hours` to*!

This is an unfortunate mishmash of two (or maybe more) JS OOP techniques and they're conflicting with each other.

Comment: Samething! Undefined results!

Comment: OK - there's something else at play then - let me check

Comment: Right, you should use `var hours`, not `this.hours`.

Comment: In this point hours var will be public reachable? I just want it private for this class only.

Comment: No `var` variables inside a function have lexical scope (i.e. effectively private)

Answer (score 1):

Well, think about where "this" points to. The first one points to the function it's in, "testFunction()" . The second one points to the function that it is in, "getHours()" but you define getHours twice, and what you return the second time is undefined because you've no longer got "this". By default, javascript returns "undefined" when there isn't something specific you want to return. As I write this I notice another answer which proposes a solution to your problem, so I won't repeat that here.